# C#-Imap:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, imap

I am trying to receive read all email subjects in an inbox, but there is an exception (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException).  The message in the exception says **"There is no such known host"**.

How can i solve this problem?

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

    client.Connect("imap.friends.com", 993, true);

    client.Authenticate("e-mail", "password");

    var inbox = client.Inbox;
    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Recent);

    for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
    {
        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
    }

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Comment: What's the message of the exception saying?

Comment: There is no such known host

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as it says:  there is no host `imap.friends.com`:

```
$ nslookup imap.friends.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find imap.friends.com: NXDOMAIN
```

You need to get the correct hostname from whomever administers the server you want to connect to.  I do not even see an `MX` record for friends.com, so it is likely this domain isn't configured for email.

Comment: If this is just a placeholder name, then the advice still holds (find the correct hostname) if not the details.